# Scraping hidden HTML (when visible = false) using Hpricot (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, screen-scraping, hpricot, scrubyt

I've come across an issue which unfortunately I can't seem to surpass, I'm also just a newborn to Ruby on rails unfortunately hence the number of questions

I am attempting to scrape a webpage such as the following:

```
http://www.yellowpages.com.mt/Malta/Grocers-Mini-Markets-Retail-In-Malta-Gozo.aspx
```

I would like to scrape The Addresses, Phones and URL of the next Page which in this case is

```
http://www.yellowpages.com.mt/Malta/Grocers-Mini-Markets-Retail-In-Malta-Gozo+Ismol.aspx
```

I've been trying just about anything i could think of but nothing seems to work due to them being set to invisible or so.

The Address is within an *h3* tag but it does not appear to be scrap-able. I've been also looking into ScRUBYt from the following url `http://www.rubyrailways.com/ajax-scraping-with-scrubyt-linkedin-google-analytics-yahoo-suggestions/`, but i really cant seem to find heads or tails of how to apply them in this case.

I would really appreciate any pointers as this is an obstacle which i really need to surpass in order to move forward on my assignment. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In the particular example you have given, the elements are not hidden, but loaded via ajax after the page load. So basically what you need is a http client which can run javascript (web browser?) to see those address and other contents.

If you want to really automate the process and scrape the data which is got through ajax or javascript, you can try [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/). Even though it is not developed for that purpose, it serves your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your specific question, but I thought I'd point to Ryan Bates' Railscast episode on screen scraping with ruby: http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi

He uses a library called scrAPI instead of ScRUBYt, since he couldn't get ScRUBYt working.  scrAPI seems to be a bit easier maybe?

I hope this helps somewhat, good luck with your assignment! :)

-John

Comment: Hi John , thanks a lot for your feedback!
the problem more than anything seems to lie within what i am trying to scrape and i can't seem to obtain the data i require due to it being hidden or so. I've had a look at scrAPI but it looks like may fall short where i need it like hpricot :s I'm also finding it particularly difficult to due scrAPI being extremely new at this =/. Thanks a lot for your assistance tho, its very appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

There is a good script posted at the [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/biterscripting/browse_thread/thread/c2d3e7d953b7dc10). It seems to extract address, etc. You may want to look at the code for the script `page.txt`.