# InvalidCastException when not casting

Tags: c#, winforms, .net

I'm using the winforms `Webbrowser` control to load a webpage, and need to wait for the page to load.
So I have a while loop that checks the `ReadyState` property, but it keeps throwing an `InvalidCastException` on the line with the comparison.

I don't understand why I would be seeing this error as I'm not doing any casting, and casting isn't even necessary because the variable is of the same type as the enum value.

Could someone please shed some light on this?

Code Below:

```
while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2500);
}
```

Edit:

[image: Screenshot of exception window]

Comment: What's the stack trace?  Are you sure it's not coming from a lower method?

Comment: This may be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912678/invalidcastexception-with-webbrowser-isbusy-or-readystate-vb-net

Comment: @DStanley the stack trace lists: [external code].  The above line.  [external code].

Comment: @DarkKight666 Please click the ["Copy Exception Detail to Clipboard"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx) link and copy the entire text in to your question [as a edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23270330/edit).

Comment: I don't have that... see screenshot above.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just subscribe to the [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event instead of using a loop?

```
private void wb_DocumentCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do stuff after the page has loaded
}
```

Comment: The code after the page load needs values set before which (correct me if I'm wrong) cannot be passed to this event.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, was calling the readystate property from a different thread.  Would have been nice to be told this was the problem as I was with other things, instead of a completely unrelated error message, but oh well.