# How can I automate filling a Word template form?

Tags: windows, macos, automated-tests

I am just beginning automated testing, and I need to test the functionality of a template in Microsoft Word on both Mac and Windows 10. This template comes complete with what I believe is a VB form. I want to populate the form, and then read the saved file. Does anyone know how I might be able to do this with Python, Java, or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automate website log-in and form filling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731752/automate-website-log-in-and-form-filling)

Comment: This is not a duplicate as this is within Word itself and not a web form.

Comment: `PyAutoGUI` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Since, that is a desktop app, you can't use Selenium.

You can try [sikulix](http://sikulix.com/) or AutoIt.